# Why does mutex lock in match cause a deadlock even in the None case?

Tags: rust, mutex, rust-tokio

The following code only reaches the "Obtaining Lock..." print statement, and it appears the initial match condition is *retaining* a lock on the mutex that cannot be obtained in setting client, leading to the program hanging.

```rust
let node = match configuration.lock().await.instance_stack.lock().await.get_mut(&ip) {
    Some(n) => n.to_owned(),
    None => {
        println!("No node currently exists, creating and registering a new node.");

        println!("[mutex]: Obtaining Client Lock...");
        // Does not obtain the following lock
        let client = &configuration.lock().await.client;
        // Never reaches here.
        println!("[mutex]: Obtained Lock on Client.");
        ...
    }
};
```

My question is: does the `None` condition not drop the mutex guard? And if not, how can you drop the guard?

---

For reference, I create a node struct in this `None` condition as it does not already exist - so I cannot simply take it out of the match statement entirely as I will at some point need to reference the retrieved item to check its existence.

The `configuration` variable is a `Arc<Mutex<MeshState>>` and `MeshState` is:

```rust
pub struct MeshState {
    pub client: Client,
    pub instance_stack: Stack,
}
```

This is running in a `tokio` environment under a handler for a `warp` route.

Comment: What library is the mutex from?

Comment: also you shouldn't mix up your code like that it makes it harder to read for no reason

Comment: I'm using `tokio::sync::Mutex`, I just pulled the struct from another file to help with context, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I recommend reading the blog post [A Rust match made in hell](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/a-rust-match-made-in-hell) by fasterthanlime. Its long, but it is fun to read and leads up to this exact kind of deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the configuration mutex is not released. `The lock()` function  waits to get the lock. In this case, you locked it earlier and it wasn't released.

The lock of the [mutex](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.7/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) in that library

> does not block and the lock guard can be held across await points.

The [docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.7/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use) here say that

> it is ok and often preferred to use the ordinary Mutex from the
> standard library in asynchronous code.

Basically the mutex didn't release because that was how it was designed.

What you should do is use the standard library mutex, then wrap that chained logic in a function or at least a block and put an `async` on it.

Then put that value in the match.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing all of your code, here's my rough example of how to achieve the code you wrote above (this could be wrong as I can't check the types of your code). Also this code assumes the configuration was already cloned into whatever async method this is.

```rs
let configuration = configuration.lock().await;

let node = match configuration.instance_stack.get_mut(&ip) {
   Some(n) => n.to_owned(),
   None => {
      let client = &configuration.client;
      // ....
   }
};

// If you need to release the lock before the end of the method this code is in:
drop(configuration);
```

Comment: This probably isn't super helpful but might point you in a better direction.

Comment: Yep, this solution works - Alex gave a more detailed explanation as to why, but many thanks!

Comment: Hopefully somebody can edit our answers together one day lol. I'll edit my answer to point to his explanation.